# Lambda function reads CloudwatchLogs from another function, sends specific lines from the logs in an email via SNS. But its sending 4-5 emails

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-serverless

So the setup is

**Data Validator Function**: Runs 24 Queries on a redshift database, outputs the response of those queries in the function logs.

**Email Sender Function**: Reads the latest CloudWatch Logs of the Data Validator Function, then inside the code im only choosing the specific lines with NOTICE: ... in them.

**SNS Topic With Email Subscription**

Then the email sender function sends all the lines in an email. But it sends 4-5 emails, each of them having arbitrary number of lines, no duplication tho.

**Reason for this setup**: I cant access the query responses in the Data Validator Function, so i had to use cloudwatch logs in order to somehow get those lines and fiddle around with them in python code.

**Code for Data Validator Function**

```
import json
import datetime
import boto3
import redshift_module.pygresql_redshift_common as db_handler
from decouple import config
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

host = config('host')
port = config('port')
db_name = config('db_name')
db_user = config('db_user')
db_password = config('db_password')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    rs_conn = db_handler.get_connection(host, port, db_name, db_user,
                                        db_password)

    queries = (
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1231();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1232();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1233();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1234();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1235();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_123123();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1233();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1233();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1232();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_12123();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_123213();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_121233();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_121233();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_12223123();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_12232323();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_12333();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_123();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_12323();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_123213();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1223233();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_112323();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_121233();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_121233();",
        "call XYZ_WAREHOUSE.validation_1233333();"
    )

    for query_string in queries:
        rs_conn.query(query_string)
```

Code for Email Sender Function

```
import os
import json
from base64 import b64decode
import gzip
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    decoded_data = gzip.decompress(b64decode(event['awslogs']['data']))
    data = json.loads(decoded_data)

    logEvents = data['logsEvents']
    email_body = "\n".join([e['message'] for e in logEvents if 'NOTICE' in e['message']])
    email_client = boto3.client('sns')
    response = email_client.publish(TopicArn=os.environ.get('EMAIL_SNS_ARN'),
                                    Message=email_body,
                                    Subject='Probe Email')
```

What could be the reason for seperate emails being sent?

Comment: how are you invoking the Email Sender Function? It's really hard to say with the limited info provided.

Comment: @JonathanLeon it is being triggered by cloudwatch logs, logGroup of the data valodator selected, filter pattern ?NOTICE

Comment: Without knowing much more, it’s seem  the cloud watch trigger is doing something differently than you expect.

Comment: @JonathanLeon that seems to be the issue yeah